# HTML special characters changed to foreign characters

Tags: 6, nodes

We have a Drupal 6 website and are using tinymce for the editor. Many of our pages included the pound (£) sign as well as other special characters. All of these have now been changed into foreign symbols. The pound sign now appears as Â£ and other strange symbols such as â€“.

I've checked the source code and the original characters have been changed into the strange new characters. It seems like the only way to fix it is to manually edit all the pages. I checked the character encoding tag and this is set to utf-8.

Can anyone help with why this might have happened in one go? The only thing I can attribute it to is possibly running update.php. Also, is there an easier way to convert then all back again?

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: Looks like an issue in DB encoding

Answer (score 1):

It should work in a proper Drupal environment

> Several people have asked how to specify the character encoding that
>   Drupal uses. The short answer is: you can't.

[How can I change Drupal's character encoding](http://drupal.org/node/8408)

> Drupal uses UTF-8 for encoding all its data. This is a Unicode
>   encoding, so it can contain data in any language. You no longer need
>   to worry about language specific encodings for your website (such as
>   Big5, GB2312, Windows-1251 or 1256, ...). Also, when Drupal imports
>   external XML data (such as RSS or XML-RPC), it is automatically
>   converted into UTF-8 (iconv support for PHP will be required for most
>   encodings).

[From Stackers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1680733/827525)